# Как расшифровать двоичный код?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Как расшифровать двоичный код? Вы ответите - никак. Нужно иметь исходники. 
Встречный вопрос - как его расшифровывают браузеры? Если есть шифратор, значить есть и дешифратор. Верно?

Comment: Это как браузеры расшифровывают двоичный код?

Есть дизассемблеры - они двоичный код в чуть более читаемый вид переделывают.

Хотя на лабах в свое время в универе мы писали на двоичном. Ну или почти на двоичном)

Comment: смотря что вы называете двоичным кодом, есть же еще машинный. Есть модемы или сетевушки, которые принемают ток, как 0 или 1 по своит таблицам переводят в знак и тд до нужного значение или представления. есть еще двоичная система счисления и разные уровни представления информации, которой занимаются интерпритаторы.

Comment: Аж стало интересно, что такого двоичного могут расшифровывать браузеры, если бы такое было, их можно было бы сравнить с дуршлаком, через который процеживали бы сетевых червей, притом всех подряд

Comment: может имеется ввиду сильно обсфуцированный js код?

Comment: Не знаю, что имел в виду первоначальный автор вопроса, но у меня вопрос похожий. Поясню: ехал по дороге в Европе, увидел спорт-кар с рег.номером 101010 (там, как известно, можно любой номер себе придумать и получить). Во-первых, красиво, а во-вторых, интересно, что он там написал (зашифровал) на своем рег.знаке.

Answer (score 4):

Что вы подразумеваете под выражением **"двоичный код"**? Обычный "двоичный код" вида:

```
 00110010
```

очень просто преобразовывается в число в десятиричной системе методом "степени двойки" =)
Так, например:

```
    00110010 = (0*2^0)+(1*2^1)+(0*2^2)+(0*2^3)+(1*2^4)+(1*2^5) = 0+2+0+0+16+32 = 50
```

---

Или, быть может, вы имеете ввиду "расшифровку" исходного кода браузера, чего-то там? =)

Answer (score 3):

Наверное автор спрашивает о том, что в браузер попадают единички и нолики из сетевого кабеля, а он их как-то превращает в текст и картинки.

Так вот, обмен данными идет по определенным протоколам, с кучей проверок типа контрольных сумм и т.п., так что браузер знает что ему передают, а не просто интерпретирует какой-то поток 101010...
Плюс есть несколько разных уровней в архитектуре сети.

Вам надо либо читать про устройство сети, либо не забивать этим голову и работать с тем что видите.

Answer (score 0):

Если смотреть по тегам, то тебе желательно ознакомиться с этой статьей 
[Байт-код](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

и искать в гугле необходимые тебе декомпиляторы байт-кода